# What package/app is actually running when doing dialer codes

Tags: samsung, intents, dialer-codes, samsung-galaxy-s-21

I am currently trying to figure out another way to access my Samsung Galaxy S21 Ultra's Secret Menus accessed via the dialer codes. My phone cannot open almost all of the dialer code, probably due to restrictions. I figured out how to open the Phone info(The one with the preferred network Setting) menu via an intent, but I'm now trying to look for the other ones like `4636` and `9090`

I then realized I just need to know the package and the class and that stuff to open it. The question is, what are the packages.

I'm basically looking for what package is opening all of these secret menus, and how to execute the dialer codes through that package via intents, or if there is another way to open these secret menus without the dialer.

Please know that I don't actually code intents and use something like automate or Macrodroid to run intents. I am on a un-rooted device, and have no way to access adb. Basically what I'm doing is trying to configure stuff with 4g/5g while just seeing all the menus and what they offer.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: My guess is that the codes are interpreted by the layer "Phone" or "RIL" as shown in the diagram on this page: https://wladimir-tm4pda.github.io/porting/telephony.html

Comment: @Robert Would you please elaborate these layers, and how this info can help?

Comment: And based on my research, I am starting to see that there is a package called telephony. Is that actually the package that processes the dialer codes? If it is, how can I actually execute the dialer codes then?

Comment: The link contains just a standard Android system layer diagram. Unfortunately I wasn't able to find a recent one, thus I don't know if it matches your Android version. Please see it as a starting point to make yourself familiar with the lower layers of Android. As dialer codes are system specific my guess is that the actual implementation is in the two mentioned layers. If you know where the command sare implemented you can check which APIs are available to access them.